# Cannot switching view back in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a problem with switching the views in iPhone simulator.I had written a code that can switch views back and forward but now when I had run it in the simulator I found that the app only switches the view forward but I am unable to switch the view back. I am unable to trace out the problem in my code. Will be thankful if anyone had helped me trace out the problem with my code.

My code is :

SwitchingViewsViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SwitchingViewsViewController : UIViewController
{

}
-(IBAction)switchback:(id)sender;
@end
```

SwitchingViewsViewController.m

```
#import "SwitchingViewsViewController.h"
#import "secondview.h"

@interface SwitchingViewsViewController ()

@end

@implementation SwitchingViewsViewController

-(IBAction)switchback:(id)sender
{
    secondview *second = [[secondview alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:  (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}

@end
```

secondview.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface secondview : UIViewController
{

}
-(IBAction)switchview:(id)sender;
@end
```

secondview.m

```
#import "secondview.h"
#import "SwitchingViewsViewController.h"

@interface secondview ()

@end

@implementation secondview


-(IBAction)switchview:(id)sender
{
    SwitchingViewsViewController *second = [[SwitchingViewsViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
}
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you know so far? Have you confirmed that -switchview and -switchback are both called when you expect them to be? Perhaps more importantly do you realize that those methods both push _new_ modal view controllers? Assuming those are called you seem to be trying to build an ever deeper stack of modals. You probably want the top controller to dismiss itself instead.

Comment: if you got the solution make habit of accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot pratik...i just resolved it..was working on some other app and am very new to stack overflow :) .Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this in second view

```
-(IBAction)switchview:(id)sender
{
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@implementation secondview


-(IBAction)switchview:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```